# jQuery flot graph is not converted by tcpdf

Tags: graph, flot, tcpdf

I Used Flot graph to create the graph. When I try to export the graph into pdf or print. The graph I plotted is not rendering is there any other solution to print graph drawn by flot.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on you question, so I'll ask here:
How does your export code look like?

I use GFlot (Google Web Toolkit wrapper for Flot) together with the CanvasText plugin at http://lessaworld.com/projects/flotCanvasText/ to render text and data onto my charts.

Have a look at this example that generates an image:
http://lessaworld.com/projects/flotCanvasText/flotCanvasTextExample2.html

You can then try to print/PDF the image.
I hope this is useful.